# Calling a stored procedure with CLOB output

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to use the `CLOB` datatype as the output parameter in my stored procedure because its resultset exceeds the storage capacity of a `var` datatype.
How do I execute the procedure? Below are the commands I had run to execute.

I tried assigning the resultset to the the `CLOB` variable using the `INTO` query as shown in the query.

`var cl CLOB;
EXECUTE procedure_name(:cl);
print cl;`

How do i declare the binding variable because if you look at the first command, I am first initializing `cl` as var I am not able to initialize it as CLOB as it is giving out an error.

This is a sample of my procedure. The actual query in the procedure is 700 lines long.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_name (cl OUT CLOB)
IS
BEGIN OPEN cl FOR
SELECT * FROM .....
statement 1
.
.
.
.
.
statement n
INTO cl
FROM
statement 1
.
.
.
statement n
EXCEPTION 
 WHEN 
  OTHERS THEN 
   DECLARE 
      err_num NUMBER  := SQLCODE; 
      err_msg VARCHAR2(512) := SQLERRM; 
      error_id_pk NUMBER; 
      error_dt DATE; 
   BEGIN
      SELECT (REGEXP_REPLACE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '[^0-9]+', ''))INTO error_id_pk FROM DUAL;
      SELECT SYSDATE INTO error_dt FROM DUAL;
      INSERT INTO ODS_CONTROL.ERROR_DETAILS(ERROR_ID, ERROR_CODE, ERROR_DATE, PROCEDURE_NAME, ERROR_MSG)
      VALUES ( error_id_pk,
               err_num,
               error_dt,
               'PRC_FLEXI_CARD',
                err_msg 
              ); 
     END; 
END;
```

Error message:

```html
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
EXECUTE procedure_name( :clb )
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object procedure_name is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: "it is giving out an error". Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52587711/edit) to include the full error message (because your error has nothing to do with the `var` variable declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] `VAR` is a keyword for declaring a variable and is not a data type; your actual error is due to using invalid syntax when you tried to define your procedure and it has not compiled.

---

`VAR` is short for `VARIABLE` and defines a PL/SQL bind variable.

This declaration has the [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm#SQPUG133):

> ```
> VAR[IABLE] [variable [type] ]
> ```
>
> where type represents one of the following:
>
> ```
> NUMBER
> CHAR
> CHAR (n [CHAR | BYTE])
> NCHAR
> NCHAR (n)
> VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR | BYTE])
> NVARCHAR2 (n)
> BLOB
> BFILE
> CLOB
> NCLOB
> REFCURSOR
> BINARY_FLOAT
> BINARY_DOUBLE
> ```

So with:

```
var cl CLOB;
```

you are declaring a variable using the `VAR` keyword and the variable is named `cl` and has the type `CLOB`.

Also, your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement has a syntax error as you cannot have the single quotes around the procedure name. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (clb OUT CLOB)
IS
BEGIN
  clb := 'test';
END;
/
```

Then:

```
VAR cl CLOB;
EXECUTE procedure_name( :cl );
PRINT cl;
```

Outputs:

```
test
```

---

**Updated**:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6f6e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ERROR_DETAILS(
  ERROR_ID       NUMBER,
  ERROR_CODE     NUMBER,
  ERROR_DATE     DATE,
  PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  ERROR_MSG      VARCHAR2(512)
)
/

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (cl OUT CLOB)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT DUMMY
  INTO   cl
  FROM   dual
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
EXCEPTION 
 WHEN 
  OTHERS THEN 
   DECLARE 
     err_num NUMBER  := SQLCODE; 
     err_msg VARCHAR2(512) := SQLERRM; 
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO /* ODS_CONTROL. */ ERROR_DETAILS(
       ERROR_ID,
       ERROR_CODE,
       ERROR_DATE,
       PROCEDURE_NAME,
       ERROR_MSG
     ) VALUES (
       TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF9' ) ),
       err_num,
       SYSDATE,
       'PRC_FLEXI_CARD',
       err_msg 
     ); 
   END; 
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6f6e/1/0)**:

```
No rows selected
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I am unable to execute using the commands. 
I am getting the following error: `PLS-00905: object 'procedure_name' is invalid`.

Comment: @GauravThantry See my update posted just before your comment. And, next time post the full error message in your question because your question makes lots of assumptions as what is wrong - none of which are actually an issue or related to the error you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi @MT0, I haven't used the quotes in my code. It's only since I cannot put the actual procedure name here, that I have enclosed it in quotes. I am still not able to execute it.

Comment: @GauravThantry Please update your question with a [MCVE] including the code that is not working ... if you are unable to do that then we are unable to help you as we cannot see the problem. The solution is that you need to debug your procedure so that it compiles but the intermediate steps you need to take are unknown as you are not sharing your problem.

Comment: Hi MT0 Apologies I was reluctant to add the actual code as it is confidential to my company. Anyways, I have added a sample code. Please let me know what can be done.

Comment: @GauravThantry Updated - but you should use a sequence for the primary key in the error table as you could get two errors with the same timestamp and the primary key will be violated.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I will be working on that. But I would also need some help with the CLOB output parameter. I am unable to execute the procedure.

Comment: @GauravThantry Please ask a new question - your current question is about the `var` keyword and it has morphed once into a question about how to compile a procedure and now you want another question answered; this is beyond the scope of your current question and you should ask a new one.

Comment: Hi MT0 as you can see in my questing, the var question wasn't emphasized in it. Its only a part of the question. My main question was how do I execute the procedure. Please refer to the first paragraph.